# Canvas LMS using ruby verion manager RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas-lms

How do I install ruby dependencies(ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev rubygems1.9.1 libhttpclient-ruby irb1.9.1) required by Canvas LMS using RVM ?

I'm using the following guide
https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start

In the above guide they expect me to install the above ruby packages using apt-get
See https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start#debianubuntu
I'm new to ruby and RoR and want to know how to use the same using rvm. Also if I follow the above method, will it affect the ruby already installed (ruby 2.1.2)RVM?
I'm trying to install the same on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) are instructions to install RVM with ruby 1.9.1:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
rvm install 1.9.1
```

Comment: There are two other dependencies. ANy answer for those? rubygems1.9.1 might not be needed as I believe it is part of rvm thing.

Comment: @iankit so ruby is installed as are irb (ruby command line) and gem (ruby package manager). To install the libhttpclient-ruby (as it is called [on debian](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/libhttpclient-ruby1.9.1/filelist) just do `gem install httpclient` ([c.f.](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=httpclient)). That should do it.